# Stopping a Hadoop 2x container

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Can someone tell how to kill a container? i see nodes are still running containers even after the application is finished and i want to know the command to kill them? Because of this issue, my subsequent applications stays in accepted state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hadoop job -list
```

This gives you jobs that are running with JobID's
To kill job

```
Hadoop job –kill JobID
```

Answer (score 0):

If yarn application is finished and some containers are still running, I'd say this is a bug somewhere. Is this a MR app? I don't think there's any commands to kill containers and anyway those should be handled by a nodemanager. Resource manager and Node manager should kill all containers when application is finished.

You didn't provide any info on what is this app, hadoop version, operating system, etc. Having said that, I once had a problem in my ubuntu hosts which had [HADOOP-9752](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9752) bug which prevented nodemanager to kill a container.